# gstreamer dynamic pipeline filesink add, getting not-negotiated error

Tags: python, dynamic, gstreamer, pipeline, pygst

This works :

```
gst-launch -e v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! tee name=splitter ! queue ! autovideosink splitter. ! queue ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=testogg.ogg
```

I'm trying to do the same in a dynamic way using python and pygst, the autovideosink branch is always there and after user input I want to attach the filesink.

This is the dynamic connection code:

```
    fileSink = self.getFileSink()
    pad = fileSink.get_static_pad('sink')
    pad.set_blocked_async(True, self.padBlockedOnRecordStart, None)
    self.player.add(fileSink)
    fileSink.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
    self.player.get_by_name('splitter').link(fileSink)
    pad.set_blocked_async(False, self.padBlockedOnRecordStart, None)
```

on linking I get this error:

```
Error: GStreamer encountered a general stream error. gstbasesrc.c(2625): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:player/GstV4l2Src:video:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that you have forgotten to add the capsfilter as an element, but I would need to see all of your linking code to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now It works!. The solution was to add "format" to capsfilter. Previous caps filter string was:

```
caps = gst.Caps('video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1')
```

and now it is:

```
caps = gst.Caps('video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)I420,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1')
```

The problem was that my webcam default output pixel format was "YUYV" and the theoraenc element in my fileSink Bin not accepted this format, so adding `format=(fourcc)I420` helped.
Still I don't know why the previous capsfilter string worked with gst-launch but I don't mind now.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure, but the error may be below ...
Please try to link before setting state to PLAYING.

```
 self.player.get_by_name('splitter').link(fileSink)    
 fileSink.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
```

I guess, the negotiation error generally occurs when caps of the two linked elements are not compatible.

Comment: I've tried that already, but it gives the same error, additionally the pipeline goes to NULL state - the element you are trying to link to an existing pipeline must be in the same state as the pipeline [dynamic pipelines](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html)